# Jenkins throws error when running pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I got a little problem with Jenkins Pipeline... To be more specific it seems like it always fails, but without any reasons, (probably there is one, but cannot find it)

Snippet of the pipeline.... (Whole Pipeline)

```
  pipeline {

     environment {
        DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS=credentials("Dockerhub")   
        APPLICATION_HOST="0.0.0.0:8000" 
        APPLICATION_PORT="8000"

     }
      
     stage("build"){

                steps{
                     script {
                         def inspectDockerNetwork = sh script: "docker network create global_store_network", returnStatus: true  

                          if (inspectDockerNetwork == 0) {
                              sh "echo 'Creating Docker Network...'"
                              sh "docker network create global_store_network"
                              sh "echo 'Network Has been Created..'"
                          }
                     }
                    dir("test_env"){
                        sh "docker-compose up -d"
                        sleep 10 
                        sh "echo 'Docker Built Image Successfully! Running Container....'"
                    }
                }
            }
     
            stage("test"){

                steps{
                    load "./test_env/version_env.groovy"

                    sh "echo 'Running Test Pipeline'"
                    sh "echo 'Running Healtcheck Test...'"
                    sh "echo 'Sleeping until the Application will be fully ready...'"
                    sleep 10    

                    script {

                        command = """curl -s -X GET -H 'accept: */*' 'http://${env.APPLICATION_HOST}:${env.APPLICATION_PORT}/healthcheck/'"""
                        responseStatus = sh(script: command, returnStdout: true).trim()
                                        
                        if (responseStatus != "200") {
                            sh "echo 'Application Responded with Failure, Not Ready for Production...'"
                            error "Health Check Stage Failure."
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                post {
                    always {
                        dir("test_env"){
                            sh "echo 'Removing Testing Environment'"
                            sh "docker-compose down"
                        }
                    }
                }  
            }. /////////// It has not start an Execution of the Deployment, So the Error Is Somewhere above ////////////////////////////////////

            stage("deployment"){

                steps {
                    load "./test_env/version_env.groovy"
            
                    sh "echo 'Running Deployment Pipeline Stage...'"
                    sh "echo 'Tagging new Image Version'"

                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(
                        credentialsId: "DockerHub", // Credential Id that should be created at Jenkins Server...
                        usernameVariable: env.DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR, // Credential Username that should be created at jenkins Server.
                        passwordVariable: env.DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW, // Credential Password that shoud be created at Jenkins Server..
                    )]){
                        sh "docker login -u ${env.DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR} -p ${env.DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW}"
                        sh "echo 'Logged In.. Into Docker.'"

                        sh "echo 'Tagging An Image'"
                        sh "docker tag new_versioned_image ${env.DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY_LINK}:latest"
                        sh "echo 'Tagged... Pushing onto docker repo.'"

                        sh "docker push ${env.DOCKERHUB_REPOSITORY_LINK}:latest"

                        sh "echo 'Tagged Successfully.. Pushing Image On Docker Hub..'"
                        sh "echo 'Image has been Pushed Successfully! Pipeline Finished.'"
                    }
                }
}
}
```

So the Output of that snippet is following...

( I've Separated Stage Logs In order to make it easier to read )

```
/////////// Build Stage ///////////////


First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials

Masking supported pattern matches of $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS or $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW

[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {

[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Store Pipeline/test_env

[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker-compose up -d
Container test_postgres_store_database  Creating
Container test_postgres_store_database  Created
Container test_store_application_server  Creating
Container test_store_application_server  Created
Container test_postgres_store_database  Starting
Container test_postgres_store_database  Started
Container test_store_application_server  Starting
Container test_store_application_server  Started

[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec
[Pipeline] sh

+ echo Docker Built Image Successfully! Running Container....
Docker Built Image Successfully! Running Container....

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)

[Pipeline] load
[Pipeline] { (./test_env/version_env.groovy)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] sh


////////////// Testing Stage goes there /////////////////////



+ echo Running Test Pipeline
Running Test Pipeline

[Pipeline] sh
+ echo Running Healtcheck Test...
Running Healtcheck Test...

[Pipeline] sh
+ echo Sleeping until the Application will be fully ready...
Sleeping until the Application will be fully ready...

[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec

[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -s -X GET -H accept: */* http://0.0.0.0:8000/healthcheck/

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
Post stage

[Pipeline] dir
Running in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Store Pipeline/test_env
[Pipeline] {

[Pipeline] sh
+ echo Removing Testing Environment
Removing Testing Environment

[Pipeline] sh
+ docker-compose down
Container test_store_application_server  Stopping
Container test_store_application_server  Stopping
Container test_store_application_server  Stopped
Container test_store_application_server  Removing
Container test_store_application_server  Removed
Container test_postgres_store_database  Stopping
Container test_postgres_store_database  Stopping
Container test_postgres_store_database  Stopped
Container test_postgres_store_database  Removing
Container test_postgres_store_database  Removed


///// Deployment Stage Goes there.... //////////// 

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (deployment)

Stage "deployment" skipped due to earlier failure(s)     ///// The Error Message Goes There....

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node


//// ERROR ///// 

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 7
Finished: FAILURE
```

The Problem is that it does not respond what's exactly the problem is, (just simply `skipped due to earlier failure(s)`, above logs does not shows any of the errors.

So would really appreciate any help or any suggestions how to solve this Issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing this line is failing. `responseStatus = sh(script: command, returnStdout: true).trim()`.

Comment: yeah, I've analyzed a bit what I wrote, and turned out the error was there, you are 100% right.